# Two-Way Repeated-Measure design with lme4

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures, lme4-nlme, two-way

I would like to model a treatment effect in two different groups, controlled for some co-variates (like age and education), and I assume that a two-way repeated-measure Anova would be the right approach - if yes, I have some questions on how to model this design.

I'm a bit confused on how to do this with R (and the  `lme4` package), because I found different approaches for the same design. Let's say, I have following variables:

- subject
- group (control vs treatment group)
- time (t0 vs t1, i.e. two measures for each subject)
- age (co-variate)
- education (co-variate)

Am I right, that, according to [this posting on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58745/using-lmer-for-repeated-measures-linear-mixed-effect-model), my model would look like this?

1. model: `lmer(DV ~ group * time + age + education + (1+time|subject), mydata)`

Then I found [this tutorial](http://www.uni-kiel.de/psychologie/rexrepos/posts/anovaMixed.html#mixed-effects-analysis-1). Following these instructions, my model would look like this?

2. model: `lmer(DV ~ group * time + age + education + (1|subject) + (1|group:subject) + (1|time:subject), data=mydata)`

Now I have two questions:

a) which of the two above models is correct? or do both work?

b) my data is in long format, how should my variable `subject` look like? the same value for each measured person, i.e. a value appears twice in this variable (for *person A in group X* at **t0** and *person A in group X* at **t1** the same value), or should each row/observation be indicated by a new, unique ID?

Comment: Ok, I could answer myself at least point _b)_. When I use a subject-variable, where each "row" of the data frame gets a new ID, ' lme4' throws an error saying that number of grouping levels must be less than number of observations. So the variable subject-ID needs identical values for each subject (person) at t0 and t1 (in between subjects).

Answer (score 2):

I think I now know which model works, so I can answer the question for myself. Both models work, it depends on the subject-variable.

To get a better understanding of which random parts to use, I have computed four models:

```
fit <- lme4::lmer(DV ~ group * time + age + education +
                    (1|lfd) + 
                    (1|group:lfd) +
                    (1|time:lfd),
                  data = mydata)

fit2 <- lme4::lmer(DV ~ group * time + age + education +
                    (1+time|lfd), data = mydata)

fit3 <- lme4::lmer(DV ~ group * time + age + education +
                    (1|subject), data = mydata)

fit4 <- lme4::lmer(DV ~ group * time + age + education +
                    (1|lfd), data = mydata)
```

All four models produce the same (fixed-effects) results. `lfd` is a repeating number, which repeats an ID 4 times: once per group and once per time (so 2 groups by 2 time points are 4 groups).

`subject` is a repeated ID for each group in both time points, i.e. I have just 2 groups (group A and B), not further distinguish by `time`.

For me, the quintessence - after trying to better understand 2-way repeated measures with mixed models - is:

> I think that you don't need to worry about nesting as long as you don't repeat subject ID's within treatment groups.

(as already mentioned [in this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/59059/54740), but at that time not understood by me. ;-) )

Comment: [This blog posting](http://rpsychologist.com/r-guide-longitudinal-lme-lmer) provides a very good overview of making decisions on model designs and how to apply `lmer` or `lme` function.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question... What does "lfd" stand for? I see your explanation about its being a repeating number... Can you show the head(data)?

Comment: `lfd` is a repeated number, which is unique in group A at time 0, group B at time 0, group A at time 1 and group B at time 1. So, each value of `lfd` appear four times (thus, subject Peter from group A and subject Mary from group B have the same value both at t0 and t1). Think of having group A at t0, 500 subjects, numbered from 1 to 500. group B at t0, also numbered from 1 to 500. group A at t1 numbered from 1 to 500 and group B at t1 numbered from 1 to 500.