# What does the 1+ mean in a formula?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I'm trying to understand the examples provided in [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58745/using-lmer-for-repeated-measures-linear-mixed-effect-model) and have tracked down a lot of syntax information.  The specific example is:

```
m2 <- lmer(Obs ~ Treatment * Day + (1+Day|Subject), mydata)
```

I'm understanding most of it, but I can't find what the `1+Day` means, particularly in the context of `(1+Day|Subject)` and trying to google `1+` is a lost cause.  Can anyone please help?

More generally, in plain English it seems like it's saying something like: The observation depends on the treatment on that day and all the daily measurements for that subject?  Is that even in the ballpark?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`+1` in R formula is intercept term. `(1+Day|Subject)` is random intercept and random slope for `Day` for levels of `Subject`.