# Creating New Variables in Regression

Tags: logistic, feature-engineering

Suppose that you have daily blood pressures for each person (call this variable $x$). The outcome variable is binary ($1$ if person will have heart attack and $0$ if person will not). Does it make sense to create an $x_{\text{sum}}$ variable which is the sum of the daily blood pressures to improve the predictive power of a logistic regression model? Or would this coefficient be $0$?

In general, does adding variables that are just sums/differences/products/quotients of other variables just introduce multicollinearity?

Answer (score 2):

**To answer your main question:**
Adding explanatory variables which are linear combinations of other explanatory variables will render the model unidentifiable by ordinary least squares. You can either use the individual measurements, or their sum/mean/median, but not both.

**Other remark**
If you have multiple measurements of the same person (e.g. blood pressure of several days), you cannot ignore the violation of independent measurements. You should use a mixed model to incorporate this dependency. You may want to look up time-series/repeated measures/longitudinal data. The random effect here is 'person'.

In R, random effects can be modeled with the `lme4` package using the function `lmer()`, e.g.:

- `lmer(y ~ x + (1|person))` (intercept)
- `lmer(y ~ x + (0 + x|person))` (slope)
- `lmer(y ~ x + (x|person))` (both)

See also this answer for example: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/59059