# Mixed model fixed effect interpretation doubt

Tags: r, interpretation, lme4-nlme

I'll try to summarize my problem as clearly as possible (and yes, I read a million other threads with similar problems, googled it, and I'm still here begging for help).

I am trying to generate a mixed effect model on my dataset which originates from my study in which:

Two group of patients with two different treatments are scanned the same day at 6 different timepoints. While originally we planned to enroll 40 vs 40, due to artifacts and dropouts we only have 26 vs 34. With complete datasets.

Our endpoint in the model is called **avg**, the groups are divided by the factor **wp** (two levels 1 and 4). The scan timepoint is called **timep** (six levels: -15, 0, 15, 30, 75, 90, and 105). each patient is identified by **ID**.

Taking inspiration from an answer to this post on [stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58745/using-lmer-for-repeated-measures-linear-mixed-effect-model) I generated the following model:

```
m1 <- lmerTest::lmer(avg ~ WP + timep + WP*timep + (timep| ID), 
REML= TRUE, data = SBf,
control=lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nRE="ignore"))
```

My intention were to generate a model where:

- The treatment paradigm **WP**, the scanning timepopint **timep**, and their interaction are fixed effects
- Both the intercept and the effect of the **ID** are random effects within each timepoint, to allow each subject to have different starting points and different linear changes over time.

Due to lack of data, I had to force the generation of the model with

```
control=lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nRE="ignore")
```

As suggested [in another post here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26465215/random-slope-for-time-in-subject-not-working-in-lme4)

With this chunk, the model is correctly constructed and I obtain the following output:

```r
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: avg ~ WP + timep + WP * timep + (timep | ID)
  Data: SBf
Control: lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nRE = "ignore")

REML criterion at convergence: 3449.7

Scaled residuals: 
   Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.4524 -0.2737 -0.0211  0.2715  3.3163 

Random effects:
Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr                         
ID       (Intercept) 1875.6   43.31                                 
         timep0      5677.4   75.35    -0.36                        
         timep15     1191.4   34.52    -0.37  0.53                  
         timep75      683.8   26.15    -0.18  0.27  0.52            
         timep90      691.2   26.29    -0.03 -0.02  0.34  0.89      
         timep105     936.3   30.60     0.09 -0.28  0.26  0.59  0.87
Residual              165.6   12.87                                 
Number of obs: 360, groups:  ID, 60

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  200.3324     7.7482  58.0012  25.855  < 2e-16 ***
WP4           -6.0747    11.7704  58.0012  -0.516 0.607749    
timep0        -0.1412    13.2937  57.9935  -0.011 0.991563    
timep15       -3.6118     6.6917  57.9953  -0.540 0.591446    
timep75       -9.1824     5.4636  57.9989  -1.681 0.098211 .  
timep90       -7.7000     5.4836  58.0036  -1.404 0.165593    
timep105     -10.2853     6.1055  58.0058  -1.685 0.097440 .  
WP4:timep0    88.2112    20.1945  57.9935   4.368 5.25e-05 ***
WP4:timep15   47.5733    10.1655  57.9953   4.680 1.77e-05 ***
WP4:timep75   31.5016     8.2998  57.9989   3.795 0.000354 ***
WP4:timep90   24.7538     8.3301  58.0036   2.972 0.004307 ** 
WP4:timep105  30.9122     9.2749  58.0058   3.333 0.001501 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
           (Intr) WP4    timep0 timp15 timp75 timp90 tmp105 WP4:t0 WP4:15 WP4:75 WP4:90
WP4         -0.658                                                                      
timep0      -0.384  0.253                                                               
timep15     -0.410  0.270  0.514                                                        
timep75     -0.253  0.166  0.284  0.511                                                 
timep90     -0.138  0.091  0.051  0.377  0.765                                          
timep105    -0.025  0.016 -0.178  0.318  0.560  0.762                                   
WP4:timep0   0.253 -0.384 -0.658 -0.338 -0.187 -0.034  0.117                            
WP4:timep15  0.270 -0.410 -0.338 -0.658 -0.336 -0.248 -0.210  0.514                     
WP4:timep75  0.166 -0.253 -0.187 -0.336 -0.658 -0.504 -0.368  0.284  0.511              
WP4:timep90  0.091 -0.138 -0.034 -0.248 -0.504 -0.658 -0.502  0.051  0.377  0.765       
WP4:timp105  0.016 -0.025  0.117 -0.210 -0.368 -0.502 -0.658 -0.178  0.318  0.560  0.762
```

Now, as a real newbie I have the following questions:

- Is the model written in a way that generates what I intend it to?
- Do I have to interpret timep within the random effects, when I do know that I want it as a fixed one? and if Not, how should I interpret the variance due to timep in the random effects part of the output? Should I just count that a residual variance?
- In the fixed effects part, I do see significant *P*s in every WP1 vs WP4:timepx at all timep. Shouldn't I also find a significant *P* with WP4 only? am I missing something? from other analysis I can confirm  that, at each timep, WP1 is significantly different from WP4, which is expected.

> TL DR: Huston we have a newbie problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, your variable `timep` is currently a factor. Since you want "each subject to have different starting points and different ***linear*** changes over time", you need to turn `timep` into a numeric variable (e.g. `as.double(timep)`).

Once you have done this change, your formula will contain three different liner effects (slope) for `timep`: one overall slope (fixed effect), a slope per value of `WP` (fixed interaction effect), and a slope per individual (random effect). So the overall linear effect of `timep` will be "corrected" for each value of `WP`, and this again will be "corrected" by an extra slope for each individual.

Similarly with the offset: You will have an offset for each level of `WP`, which will be "corrected" by individual-wise offsets (from the random effect).

Comment: Dear Frank, Thanks for the help! I didnt notice R converted it to a factor. Just one last question if you wouldnt mind: will the model also contain an intercept adjustment for the `WP` group?

Comment: Yes, the interaction term `WP*timep` with `WP` being a factor and `timep` a numeric, will result in an adjustment of the `timep` slope for the levels of `WP`.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you very much Frank. It was really appreciated.